Equivalent to wrapup_run for log file?
Using lualatex with TeXlive 2024, Linux, compiling via Terminal command.
Thanks to the luatex wrapup_run (and help previously provided at this forum), I can write a message to Terminal, which appears as the very last message, just above return to command line. The usual "Here's how much..." messages (which I ignore) appear higher up. MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifluatex\usepackage{fontspec}\fi
\AtEndDocument{
  \ifluatex
    \directlua{
      luatexbase.add_to_callback('wrapup_run',
        function ()
          texio.write('\luaescapestring{\hlvb}') end, "final message"
      )
    }%
  \fi
  \wlog{\hlvb}
}
\def\hlvb{^^JHasta la vista, baby.^^J}
\begin{document}
Stick 'em up.
\end{document}

I can compile that with either pdflatex or lualatex. Only lualatex writes the Terminal message where I want it. This is expected behavior.
What I would like to do, if possible, is write the message at the very end of the log file.
Currently, \wlog writes the message above "Here's how much..." info.
From looking at other questions here, it seems that I cannot use directlua with \wlog, because the log file is controlled directly by LaTeX. If I attempt to open the log for writing with Lua, bad things happen. No surprise.
So my question is: Without using \directlua (but compiling with lualatex), is there an equivalent of wrapup_run that will defer a log message to the very end of the log, after the "Here's how much..." info?

You can replace the Here's how much.. message with the stop_run callback. And I don't really understand the second-to-last paragraph, an example would be appreciated.

Regarding the second-to-last paragraph: I tried using `\luaescapestring{\wlog{\hllllllllvb}}' but it complains that it cannot get to the log file. This, I understand.

wrapup_run is called after the log file is closed so you can append to it from Lua. For other engines the LaTeX enddocuemnt/end hook writes as late as possible, but that is before the memory usage stats.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}
\def\hlvb{Hasta la vista, baby.}

\ifluatex
 \directlua{
      luatexbase.add_to_callback('wrapup_run',
        function ()
        f=io.open("\jobname.log", "a")
        f:write("\hlvb")
        f:close()
        end,
        "final message"
      )
    }
\else
% as late as possible without Lua
  \AddToHook{enddocument/end}{\wlog{^^J\hlvb^^J}}
\fi

\begin{document}
Stick 'em up.
\end{document}

produces a luatex log ending
Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 517 strings out of 475630
 100000,552014 words of node,token memory allocated
 406 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 4 attribute, 48 glue_spec,
 4 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:22,3:4,4:1,5:23,6:2,7:54,9:18
 23490 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+600000
 15 fonts using 723367 bytes
 35i,5n,49p,125b,125s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
</usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.o
tf>
Output written on bb047.pdf (1 page, 3682 bytes).

PDF statistics: 15 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 8 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 100000000)

Hasta la vista, baby.


Works as intended (for lualatex), and the pdflatex folks will just have to survive. Before asking the question I had tried opening the log, but apparently my programming was simply wrong. By the way, what is the purpose of the aaa document, or did you copy/paste too much?

@rallg oh sorry I started with my own test then decided to use your text and accidentally left in both i will clean up
